# .NET MAUI Picker: Preventing User Text Input

Tags: .net, datepicker, maui, picker

I have a problem with Pickers and DatePickers in .NET MAUI. I'm using pickers to display options for the user to choose from, which I obtain from an API. However, if I enter text using my keyboard, the picker detects the text input and allows the text to be written inside. I need my pickers to be 'read-only', if that makes sense. The user should only be able to choose options and not write inside them. Here's an example:

[image]

This is the code. I don't think it's very relevant (the problem exists in both pickers)

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
    <!-- Centro de trabajo y Picker -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Centro de trabajo" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Frame Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Secondary}" Padding="15,0" CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="Black">
            <Picker Title="Selecciona un centro de trabajo"                          
                    x:Name="CentroTrabajoPicker"
                    HorizontalOptions="End" 
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    TextColor="Black"/>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>

    <!-- Fecha y DatePicker -->
    <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Fecha" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        <Frame Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"  Padding="15,0" CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="Black" >
            
            <DatePicker Date="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" 
                        x:Name="FechaPickerMenu"
                        Format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
                        HorizontalOptions="End"/>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Does this only occur when you use a hardware keyboard with an emulator?

Comment: I have like a 100 pickers in my app and none of them do that, the s/w keyboard never shows up how do you do that?

Comment: That's what I was wondering, too. Maybe by pressing the tab button to focus the picker? That's usually not possible on actual mobile devices...

Comment: I dont need to click anywhere, in fact if I click it doesnt even gets focus, if I write on my hardware keyboard, It writes on the first picker in the class, Its really weird

Comment: Is that a realistic scenario for end users? Will this ever happen in production?

Comment: I really dont think so, if its just a hardware keyboard bug, is not a big deal I guess

Comment: This scenario is unrealistic in a non development environment

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on the GitHub and you can follow up this thread [Android Picker Issue (User can input text)](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8265).

Here is the workaround you can refer to [disable the key input of Picker](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8265#issuecomment-1473438740).